# Magento - Filter Category list by category attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, filter, categories

I have a list of store categories, and everything is working well except for one thing. I would like the list of categories to omit any that are set as 'Include in Navivation Menu = No'.

I can tell at this point that this attribute is not being loaded, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out where to place the filter. Currently, I am getting my category list via:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
```

Followed by:

```
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category) : ?>
<?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
...
...
```

At this point, I have my category objects how I want them. But if I run a debug on these objects, the 'include_in_menu' attribute is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason:

```
<?php $_subCategory->getIncludeInMenu() ?>
```

Was not working for me after I ran:

```
<?php foreach($_parentCategory->getChildrenCategories() as $_subCategory) : ?>
```

The object was still the same model, but ['include_in_menu'] was no longer part of the object. I don't like this solution, but I just reconverted the object back:

```
<?php $_subCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subCategory->getId()) ?>
```

And then it worked fine. Not sure why getting the children would strip down the object, but it does.